# Why does a metaclass not have access to the attributes inhereited from a subclass of a class defined by the metaclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, metaclass

Class `Foo` is defined with a metaclass `Meta`. The metaclass loops over the class attributes and prints them to screen.

Class `Bar` subclasses `Foo`. However, the metaclass does not print the inherited attributes from Bar.

Why doesn't the metaclass have access to `Foo`'s attributes inherited in `Bar`? What am I not understanding about python's metaclass system?

Here is the sample code in `2.7`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "bases = {}".format(bases)
        items = {k:v for k,v in attrs.iteritems() if not k.startswith('__')}
        for k,v in items.iteritems():
            print k, v

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    hi = 1

# This prints:
# bases = (<type 'object'>,)
# hi 1

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

# This prints:
# bases = (<class '__main__.Foo'>,)

Foo.hi
#prints 1
Bar.hi
#prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `attrs` parameter to `__init__` only contains the attributes **for that class**, not for its bases.

A `Bar` object does not have an attribute `hi`. Instead, when you ask for `Bar.hi` the  lookup will start at `Bar`, find out that it doesn't have `hi`, then look in base `Foo` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As @orlp says, `attrs` contains only the *class dictionary* for the class being created. You still have access to `hi`, however, because it's in the `__dict__` attribute of one of `Foo`'s bases. That is, you could do something similar to what you have, but recurse through the base classes and print out the entries in each base class dictionary.

Another approach is to use `dir()`, which should *roughly* return a list of all attributes a class has. I say *roughly* because a class can implement `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` to return attributes "on the fly", meaning that the class may not have a well-defined set of attributes for `dir()` to return -- see the full disclaimer [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir). But in many common cases, something like the following will work:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print "bases = {}".format(bases)
        for attr in dir(cls):
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                print attr, getattr(cls, attr)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    hi = 1

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

Which prints:

```
bases = (<type 'object'>,)
hi 1
bases = (<class '__main__.Foo'>,)
hi 1
```